# Method that returns count of its positive factors in C

Tags: c, parameters, factoring

I am trying to do a method that its function named is factor_count that accepts an integer as its parameter and returns a count of its positive factors.

For example, the six factors of 32 are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32, so the call of my method should return 6.

```
int factor_count(int number) {
  int i, count;
  for (i=1;i<=number;i++){
    if(number%1==0){
      count = number%i;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/factors-number

Answer (score 1):

`%` is the modulo operator.  It's remainder after a division.  If the remainder after division is zero you should increment count.  The remainder from dividing by 1 is always zero.

```
int factor_count(int number)
{
    int i, count = 0;

    for (i=1; i<=number; i++)
        /* increment count when the remainder is zero */
        if (number%i==0)
            count++;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `number%1==0` and replace it with `number%i==0` and 
then `count = count + 1` . Initialize `count = 0` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to try divisors: 1,2,3,...,sqrt(n).

Each iteration, note the [divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor), [quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient) and [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder).

If the reminder is 0, then the divisor is a factor.  If the quotient it is larger than the divisor, then the quotient is a new factor too.

Continue looping while the divisor is less than the quotient.

Iterating up to the `sqrt(n)` is sufficient and faster than iterating up to `n`

```
int factor_count(int number) {
  if (number <= 0) {
    return TBD_Code(n);  // OP needs to define functionality for these cases.
  }
  int count = 0;
  int quotient;   
  int divisor = 0;
  do {
    divisor++;
    quotient = number/divisor;
    int remainder = number%divisor;
    if (remainder == 0) {
      count++;
      if (quotient > divisor) count++;
    }
  } while (divisor < quotient);
  return count;
}
```

---

Improvement can include reducing the number, each time a divisor is found.
The following is not fully tested.

```
int factor_count2(int number) {
  if (number <= 0) {
    return TBD_Code(n);  // OP needs to define functionality for these cases.
  }
  int count = 0;
  int quotient;   
  int divisor = 0;
  do {
    divisor++;
    int remainder;
    do {
      quotient = number/divisor;
      remainder = number%divisor;
      if (remainder == 0) {
        number = quotient;
        count++;
        if (quotient > divisor) count++;
        else break;
      }
    } while (remainder == 0);
  } while (divisor < quotient);
  return count;
}
```

---

Even more improvements can be had with `factor_count2()` going to the next prime.

```
    // divisor++;
    divisor = next_prime(divisor);
```