# C Programming: How to add up divisors of an integer n

Tags: c

I was wondering, how can I add up the divisors displayed once I run my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I were to enter, say, 25, it would print out 1, 5. I was wondering how to add up the two numbers 1 and 5?

Comment: I didn't say `add(n)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be as simple as this? You will want to use a simple increment operator (**+=**), to increment the variable `sum`.

```
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, sum = 0;
    if( scanf("%d", &n)!= 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    printf("Sum of divisors: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Important nit: always, always validate ALL user input. (yes, I know this is a short example, but `if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`)

Answer (score 2):

> How to add up divisors of an integer n?

Iterating `n` times as with `for(i = 1; i < n; i++)` can take a *long time* when `n` is some high value, especially if code used 64-bit integers.  Instead only iterate `sqrt(n)` times - much faster

```
int factor_count(int number) {
  if (number <= 1) {
    return TBD_Code(number);  // OP needs to define functionality for these cases.
  }
  int sum = 1;
  int quotient;   
  int divisor = 1;
  do {
    divisor++;
    quotient = number/divisor;
    int remainder = number%divisor;
    if (remainder == 0) {
      sum += divisor;
      if (quotient > divisor) sum += quotient;
    }
  } while (divisor < quotient);
  return sum;
}
```

Additional improvements noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48757547/2410359).